# React Context API can't bind 'this'

Tags: reactjs, this, bind

When I type anything into the input which is inside of the `<Input>` component, I wanna execute the `handleInput()` function which is inside of the `<MainProvider>` component.

This (`onChange={store.handleInput.bind(this)}`) looks like working but it can't pass `this`.

In the console I just get `undefined` message.

Here's an example code.

```react-jsx
const MainContext = React.createContext()

class MainProvider extends React.Component {
  handleInput (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  render () {
    const store = {
      handleInput: () => this.handleInput()
    }

    return (
      <MainContext.Provider value={store}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MainContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

class Input extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MainContext.Consumer>
        {(store) => (
          <input {...this.props} onChange={store.handleInput.bind(this)} />
        )}
      </MainContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <MainProvider>
        <Input name='one' />
        <Input name='two' />
      </MainProvider>
    )
  }
}
```

How can I pass `this` in the `onChange` event? I'm using React 16.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes because you have used arrow function in MainProvider component which overrides the context being passed when you are calling function

```
  render () {
    const store = {
      handleInput: () => this.handleInput() // using arrow function here overrides the contect
    }

  }
```

Change it to

```
class MainProvider extends React.Component {
  handleInput (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }

  render () {
    const store = {
      handleInput: this.handleInput
    }

    return (
      <MainContext.Provider value={store}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MainContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

However in this case you would explicitly need to bind from child components or it will take the context from where it is called.

Comment: I've realized that if I use like you said, I can't access `this.state` in the `handleInput()` function. So the proper answer has to be like `handleInput: this.handleInput.bind(this)`.

Comment: More often than not, you don't need `onChange={store.handleInput.bind(this)}`, you would mostly have a binding in the component you have implemented this function

Comment: Since you wanted to know why was this not working, I provided an answer for that, also mentioned `However in this case you would explicitly need to bind from child components or it will take the context from where it is called.`

Comment: Now I've changed my code like this: `onChange={store.handleInput}` and `handleInput: this.handleInput.bind(this)`. And in the `handleInput()` function, I can both access `e` and `this.state`.